# Sending an item from a drop-down list in url parameter Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

Good evening,

I need to recover the element selected in a drop-down list and put it in a parameter to recover it at the level of the controller

I got the selected item with javascript and put it in an input to get it as a parameter but it doesn't work

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function GetSelectedText() {
                    var e = document.getElementById("listRoles");
                    var result = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
     
                    document.getElementById("r1").innerHTML = result;
            }
    </script>
<body>
    <form:select path="roles" multiple="false" onChange="GetSelectedText();">
            <option value="${author.role}" selected>${author.role}</option>
                 <c:forEach items="${roles}" var="r">
                <c:if test="${r!=author.role}">
                    <option value="${r}">${r}</option>
                    </c:if>
               </c:forEach>
    </form:select> 
    <input type="text" id="r1" name="role" />
        <c:url value="/modifierRole" var="url">
            <c:param name="id" value="${author.id}" />
            <c:param name="role" value="${param.role}" />
        </c:url>
    <a href="${url}">modify</a>
</body>
```

Comment: document.getElementById("r1").value for input field. Let me know if it helps

Comment: I tried it does not work either in the field I see the role that has to change but when I give it to the parameter of the url jstl it does not work

Comment: Wait what params of url? are you talking about a tag? no its only for input fields. For rule, you can give it an id and then set it with innerHTML

Comment: I put the role value in the input field :  <input type="text" id="r1" name="role" /> and 
 I give them a id =r1  but when I want to get value of field and use it in param of url it'snt working :   <c:param name="role" value="${param.role}" />